Перенос данных с 2 диапазонов листа на "Архивный" лист с последующим удалением данных с основного листа. создание кнопки снятия всех флажков
Есть таблица.
Необходимо создать кнопку макрос на листе "РАБОТА" который будет переносить содержимое со статусом "К выплате" в Столбце H4, на Лист "Архив" и удалять его с Листа "РАБОТА"
На листе "Календарь" необходимо сделать кнопку макрос, Которая будет все флажки на Листе переводить в статус "лож"
к сожалению я слишком туп, и разобраться самостоятельно у меня не вышло! Был бы признателен если бы кто-то написал бы это для меня. заранее спасибо!
